# Modifying SwiftUI Views based on non-binary data / conditions?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, boolean, swiftui

**Question:** I have a fairly large SwiftUI View that adds a country code based on my model data. My feeling is that I should extract a subview and then pass the country code in, then use a `switch`, but I just wanted to check I was not missing something and making this too complicated.

SwiftUI has a very nice method of dealing with two possible options based on a `Bool`, this is nice as it modifies a single `View`.

```
struct TestbedView_2: View {
    var isRed: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("Bilbo").foregroundColor(isRed ? Color.red : Color.blue)
    }
}
```

If on the other hand your model presents a none binary choice you can use a `switch` statement. This however returns an Independent `View` based on the case selected resulting in duplicate code.

```
struct TestbedView_3: View {
    var index: Int
    var body: some View {
        switch(index) {
            case 1:
                Text("Bilbo").foregroundColor(Color.red)
            case 2:
                Text("Bilbo").foregroundColor(Color.green)
            default:
                Text("Bilbo").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume it is simplified example. Would you show more real code/part of what do you try to achieve, alternates might depend on input?

Answer (score 2):

Here is more clean approach:

1. Only display text once - use function to get the color

```
Text("Bilbo").foregroundColor(self.getColor(index))
```

2. Create the getColor function

```
private func getColor(_ index : Int) -> Color {        
    switch index {
    case 1: return Color.red
    case 2: return Color.green
    case 3: return Color.blue
    default: return Color.clear
    }
}
```

*NOTE: I am using Color.clear as default case in the switch statement since it must be present*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that is one option that I have taken in my current code. I was almost hoping that SwiftUI 2.0 would have some way to switch on modifiers, rather than switching in Views. I think going for a custom helper function might be the best option at this stage. Much appreciated Sir.